# Is it possible to use "add service reference" option to add a self-hosted service in WCF?

Tags: wcf, service-reference, self-hosting

I am creating a WCF service. At first I had one WCF service library project and one console project which was referencing the this library. And it worked fine when I used "add service reference" in my client project, as long as the service library had a valid App.Config file.

However, now I want to combine the service library and the console host into one console project. After all, the previous console project was pretty simple. But here comes the problem: when I choose "add service reference" and give the endpoint I defined in the App.config file of the new console project, it can't find any service reference. I take it because the service will not be hostedd by wcfsvchost.exe when the add service reference function was on(and I think it makes sense). But I can't think of a way to make it work. So how am I supposed to add a service reference, if my service is one single console-hosted project?

Comment: **Yes of course!** Why do you ask?? The service needs to be up and running - then you can absolutely do a `Add Service Reference` for that service. After all: it's just a WCF service - how it's hosted is absolutely irrelevant to the client calling it.....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. I forgot to mention one thing: I tried "add service reference" with my original service library(so that wcfsvchost will make this service run), which has exactly the same files and app.config as my combined console. But when I unloaded this library, and run the combined console(I assume these two services will be the same so that the previous generated service reference can also be used for the new one), my client says "can't find endpoint". I guess it is because there is something I need to change with the generated service reference, but what exactly are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for you is to run WCF service, generate a service reference and then combine it into single application. All you will need to do is just change address in your app.config. But be careful with this, as you should change address for client part and not server part of app.config.

This approach, however, will be difficult to maintain in future, when you will decide to change your service data contract and regenerate service reference. You might want to consider the following: wrap service reference into assembly and use assembly instead. This way you will be able to regenerate you service reference whenever needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you be more specific what change I should make to "change the address in app.config"? Because I tried the service reference generated from my service library, which is basically using the same setting as my combined console project. But when I run the combined console(I unloaded the service library so wcfsvchost.exe. won't host this version), which should host exactly the same service as the service library, my client says endpoint not found. I am guessing it is because there is something different and I need to change. But I just can't figure out what

Comment: @tete Could you post your combined app.config in the question? You can remove sensitivie information. It might also be the case that you are sending requests before WCF service is up and running

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem when I was posting the app.config: I forgot to change the namespace name, it was still using the service library's namespace. Silly me.